# Is it possible to create a materialized view from two tables in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cql3

Is it possible to create a materialized view from two table in cassandra and if yes please suggest how.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one base table for each materialized view. Cheers!